# Spivak's Calculus, chapter 2 question 3 (e)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Prove that

$$ \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j \binom{n}{j} = \binom{n}{0} - \binom{n}{1} + \cdots + (-1)^n   
 \binom{n}{n} = 0$$

This only holds true when $n \ne 0$, although it wasn't specified.

I've proven this by induction, but I still have trouble understanding Spivak's proof:

$$0 = (1+ -1)^n = \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^j \binom{n}{j} $$

Can someone please provide some intuition behind this approach?

Comment: That line you quote does not look like part of an induction proof.  It looks like a complete proof in itself, from the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well $$1 + (-1) = 0,$$ so $$(1 +  (-1))^n = 0^n = 0.$$
Now use the binomial theorem, which states $$(a + b)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} a^{n - k} b^k. \tag{1}$$
The intuition here uses that $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-1)^j$ awfully looks like the RHS of $(1)$ with $a = 1$ and $b = -1$.

Comment: @JorgeBarrios Correct: For $n = 0$ we have $\sum_{j = 0}^{0} (-1)^j \binom{0}{j} = (-1)^j \binom{0}{0} = 1 \cdot 1 \ne 0$.